# How to force verbatim mode for file inclusion in rdoc

Tags: ruby, rdoc

I need to include an example program in my rdoc.  The example
program also needs to be executable so that a user can just run
the example from the command line.

I want to show the source code of the program *exactly as written* in
my rdoc formatted documentation.

From what I can see, the only way to trigger verbatim mode is to increase
the indent level.

So, how can I get my file to 'include' the example program but *not* mark
it up in any way?

I tried this:

```
# :include:example_program.rb
```

But it processes the contents of example_program.rb as non-verbatim until it reaches the first
indented code block.

Then, it treats the body of *that block* as verbatim, then when the block
ends, goes back to interpreting markup.

I want it to not interpret *any* markup for the entire duration of the
included file.

Is there some other way of delineating a verbatim section than with indentation?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I needed to indent the include directive itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#   :incude:sample_program.rb
# Other commentary that I wish to be marked up by rdoc.
```

I had been assuming that an include directive in a verbatim block would
itself be output verbatim.

Apparently, if the verbatim block consists of only an include directive, it
is processed as exactly the solution to my problem.